# Como mudar o nome padrão do botão OK do bootbox?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Eu estou usando o bootbox em minha aplicação e gostaria de saber como fazer para mudar o nome padrão do alert que está como OK, abaixo o meu script:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Ajax_Teste")', function (response) {
            alert("getJson sucesso");
        }).fail(function (data) {
            bootbox.alert("Não foi possível processar a sua requisição. abra o log para consulta" + data.responseJSON.msg);
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  bootbox.alert({
    message: "Não foi possível processar a sua requisição. abra o log para consulta",
    buttons: {
        ok: {
            label: 'Enviar o relatório de Erro.',
            // Se quiser mudar a classe tbm
            className: 'btn-danger'
        },
    },
    callback: function(){
        //seu código aqui
        console.log('clicou');
    }

   }) 
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.js"></script>
```

Exemplo com confirmação:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  bootbox.confirm({
    message: "Não foi possível processar a sua requisição. abra o log para consulta",
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Enviar o relatório de Erro.',
            // Se quiser mudar a classe tbm
            className: 'btn-success',
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'Não enviar',
            // Se quiser mudar a classe tbm
            className: 'btn-danger',
        }
    },
    callback: function(result){
        //seu código aqui
        if(result)        
          console.log("confirmou");
        else
          console.log("cancelou");
    }

   }) 
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.js"></script>
```

Comment: Na verdade Leandro o botão ok vai se tornar ENVIAR RELATÓRIO DE ERRO, no qual ele vai capturar o meu log de erro e enviar para o meu email. E quando usei esse exemplo ai o alert não esta mais sendo exibido!!!

Comment: então você precisa de um callback, eu recomendaria trocar o alert pelo confirm ou prompt... assim o usuário tem a opção de enviar o relatório ou simplesmente fechar. Obs.: se o usuário sempre vai enviar o relatório, você não precisa fazer esse segundo post no client... basta você enviar na action que retorna o erro.

Comment: Como não entendo muito bem, poderia dar uma resposta mostrando como fazer pelo prompt, e sim, sempre o usuario vai enviar para o email!

Comment: Mas se você sempre quer receber o relatório, se ele não tiver capturando nada que está na tela do usuário, não faz sentido dar essa ação/opção para ele. Como eu disse, faça o envio do relatório no backend, afinal de contas você já capturou o erro e aqui estaria apenas mostrando para o usuário.

Comment: Nessa situação aqui cara, sempre vai ter algo capturado. Por isso preciso fazer isso, porque só entra nessa condição se tiver algo capturado, entendeu??? Me mostra ai dentro do meu contexto como ficaria esse prompt, pq nunca fiz isso!

Comment: Adicionei o `confirm`, mas eu digo capturado do DOM que está sendo exibido... pq a mensagem de erro que você mostra vem do servidor

Comment: Leandro, funcionou perfeitamente agora eu não entendi o que fazer com o callback, ali devo inserir as configurações SMTP para o envio ser realizado para o email???

Comment: Não, você não pode enviar e-mails por javascript, vai ter que criar uma Action na sua controller, fazer um post para ela e enviar pelo asp.net... e agora você vai entender porque desde a outra pergunta eu dizia que você deveria fazer o envio no momento da captura do erro... :P

Answer (score 1):

Na documentação tem bons exemplos: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html

Para o seu caso, basta definir `buttons`:

```
bootbox.alert({
    message: "Não foi possível processar a sua requisição. abra o log para consulta" + data.responseJSON.msg",
    buttons: {
        ok: {
            label: 'Label do botão OK',
            className: 'btn-success'
        }
    }
});
```